# D, setting class property, no identifier for declarator

Tags: class, compiler-errors, d

I'm just getting started with D and this is completely strange. Here's my code:

```
class User
{
    int id;
    string name;
}

User b = new User();
b.name = "Edwin";
```

And here's my error:

```
root@d-testing:~/Sail/source# dmd nonsense.d 
nonsense.d(8): Error: no identifier for declarator b.name
nonsense.d(8): Error: Declaration expected, not '='
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here? Every class example I've seen does it this way.

Comment: It is a good question actually, because many people use(d) languages where arbitrary statements may appear anywhere in the file. This is especially true with scripting languages.

Comment: This is absolutely hilarious to me since I use C and C# a lot. For some silly reason because some of the examples I saw didn't define any function, it didn't click. Too much Python lately :D

Comment: Python was the first language that came to my mind when I saw your comment. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't execute code directly in the root of the file like that in D. You are allowed to declare new variables, such as the 'User b = new User()' (though it may not do what you expect), but not execute arbitrary statements like adjusting b.name.

You need to wrap the code you want to execute in a main() method, such as:

```
void main() {
    User b = new User();
    b.name = "Edwin";
}
```